# How to get table row by id and then change it's value / html

Tags: jquery

I have a table its generated by jquery.

```
<table id="redTable" class="rwd-table table-centered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>aaa</th>
      <th>bbb</th>
      <th>ccc</th>
      <th>ddd</th>
      <th>eee</th>
      <th>fff</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="46603693">
      <td><span>Image cell</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="30041170">
      <td><span>Image cell</span></td>
      <td><span>Change it to Image</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Change it to 10</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to search a row where id equal 30041170;
Than i want to change the cells value.
I tried `$('#id').find('30041170')` it. Maybe i got the row with this.

Its fine? If fine, how can i change the cells?

Sorry about this, I am newbie in frontend jq, and its so hard for me.
I hope someone can help me.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#30041170 td span').eq(1).html('Image');
$('#30041170 td span').eq(3).html('10');
```

Comment: Have you tried those selectors? They're invalid, and will fail.

Comment: That's interesting, they're working now. They shouldn't, ID selectors starting with an unescaped digit are invalid. Previously in jQuery, they only worked if they were on their own (`$("#1111")`), not when used in combination. I just tried with jQuery 2.x and 1.10, though, and apparently they've decided to give up on requiring valid selectors. I'd **strongly** recommend not relying on invalid selectors.

Comment: ohh... thanks for the try :) and sorry i haven't used the 1.x as i always go for updated versions :)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried `$('#id').find('30041170')`

No, that will throw an error, you're trying to use a number as a tag selector.

If you can, change the code generating the table to put a letter in front of those numeric IDs, e.g. `id="x30041170"` rather than `id="30041170"`. Then use `$("#x30041170")` to get the row.

If you can't, you can use `$("#redTable [id='30041170'])` to get the row. (If you used `$("#30041170")` it would work with current versions of jQuery, but it's an invalid selector and not guaranteed.)

Once you have a selector for the row, you can add to it to select a specific cell via `:eq` and the span within it. For instance, to set the third cell's `span`'s contents to "10":

```
$("#redTable [id='30041170'] > td:eq(2) span").text("10");
```

Or get the row:

```
var row = $("#redTable [id='30041170']);
```

...and then address the cells in it:

```
row.children().eq(2).find("span").text("10");
```

Live Example:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#redTable [id='30041170'] > td:eq(2) span").text("10");
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click To Change">
<table id="redTable" class="rwd-table table-centered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>aaa</th>
      <th>bbb</th>
      <th>ccc</th>
      <th>ddd</th>
      <th>eee</th>
      <th>fff</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="46603693">
      <td><span>Image cell</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="30041170">
      <td><span>Image cell</span></td>
      <td><span>Change it to Image</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Change it to 10</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following snippet.

```js
//To change all the td values 
$('#30041170 > td > span').html("new image");

//To change first td value
$('#30041170 > td:eq(0) > span').html("first td");

//To change last td value
$('#30041170 > td:last() > span').html("last td");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="redTable" class="rwd-table table-centered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>aaa</th>
      <th>bbb</th>
      <th>ccc</th>
      <th>ddd</th>
      <th>eee</th>
      <th>fff</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="46603693">
      <td><span>Image cell</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="30041170">
      <td><span>Image cell</span></td>
      <td><span>Change it to Image</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Change it to 10</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
      <td><span>Loading</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```